# How to specify a data frame and column in a function containing a `for` loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a function that returns all the observations in a specified data frame and column that have a number of letters < 5. For example if an observation was `dogs` it would be returned, but if another observation was `store` it would not be returned.

This is the code I have written:

```
count_length <- function(dataset, column_named){
  
  for (i in dataset$column_named)
    if (nchar(dataset$column_named[i] < 5)){
      paste("problem with ",i)
    }
  
  
}

count_length(dataset = df,
             column_named = pets)
```

The following error is returning:

```
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `column_named`.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this and why it is happening? Is it related to the use of `$` I wonder?

Comment: You should take a look at indexing in loops in R, it is not like in other languages. You likely need a `seq_along` the length of the column. Alternatively, you can use `*apply` and if you're feeling fancy, the `tidy` suite.

Comment: Even if you fix the above, you can't index using character vectors using `$`, you should use `dataset[[column_named[i]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. It's indeed related to the use of `$`, as it is a function and cannot evaluate variables inside it.

You can try `dataset$[column_named]` for a dataframe or `dataset$[[column_named]]` for a vector

Longer explanation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/15012262)